# In, yii2 I want to insert sinlge row on one table as well as multiple rows in another table

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In, yii2 I want to insert sinlge row on one table as well as multiple rows with same id in another table

```html
controller code --

$modelcid = $modeld->categoryid;
$modelpc = $modeld->productcode;
$modelqty = $modeld->qty;
$arrayvalue[]= array('id'=>$modelcid,'pc'=>$modelpc,'qty'=>$modelqty);
$i=0;
foreach($arrayvalue as $key=>$val) {
 $purchaseid = $modeld->purchaseid = $modelm->purchaseid;
 $cid = $modeld->categoryid =$val['id'][$i];
 $pc = $modeld->productcode =  $val['pc'][$i];
 $qty = $modeld->qty = $val['qty'][$i];
 $remarks = $modeld->remarks = $modelm->remarks;
 if($modeld->save()){
   $i++;
  }
 }

"$modeld->save()"  it saves only first entry.
```

Answer (score 2):

The [isNewRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#$isNewRecord-detail) attribute of `\yii\db\ActiveRecord` determines:

> Whether the record is new and should be inserted when calling `save()`

When a new record is saved, this variable is set to `false` so your code is creating the record in the first run of the loop and updating it in subsequent runs.

You need to set this variable explicitly to `true` for each record to be saved. You also need to unset your primary key field:

```
foreach ($arrayvalue as $key => $val) {
    $modeld->isNewRecord = true;
    unset($modeld->id); //assuming `id` is your primary key field
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can use new instance of `$modeld` in the loop:

```
foreach ($arrayvalue as $key => $val) {
    $modeld = new ModelD; //assuming your model class is ModelD 
    ...
```